# error al refrescar pagina Cannot GET /home

Tags: html, nodejs, reactjs, react-router-dom

tengo un inconveniente no se si alguien pudiera ayudarme esta es mi pagina y cuando voy  a las rutas me cargan perfecto los componentes pero al dar al boton refrescar [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y dar al boton refrescar pagina me sale
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> import './api.css'; import './App.css'; import React, { useEffect ,
> Suspense} from 'react'; import { Inicio } from './components/Inicio'
> import { NavBar } from './components/layout/NavBar'; import { Footer }
> from './components/layout/Footer'; import { BrowserRouter as Router,
> Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom'; import store from './store';
> import { loadUser } from './actions/user_actions'; import
> ProtectedRoutes from './routes/Protected_routes';
>
> // Componentes dinámicos const Banner = React.lazy(() =>
> import('./components/banner')); const AboutUs = React.lazy(() =>
> import('./components/abouts_us')); const Services = React.lazy(() =>
> import('./components/services/services')); const ServiceDetails =
> React.lazy(() => import('./components/services/service_details'));
> const Login = React.lazy(() => import('./components/users/login'));
> const Register = React.lazy(() =>
> import('./components/users/register')); const Profile = React.lazy(()
> => import('./components/users/profile')); const UpdateProfile = React.lazy(() => import('./components/users/updateProfile')); const
> UpdatePassword = React.lazy(() =>
> import('./components/users/updatePassword')); const ForgotPassword =
> React.lazy(() => import('./components/users/forgotPassword')); const
> ResetPassword = React.lazy(() =>
> import('./components/users/resetPassword')); const Reviews =
> React.lazy(() => import('./components/reviews/reviews')); const
> Comentarios = React.lazy(() =>
> import('./components/reviews/comentarios')); const Dashboard =
> React.lazy(() => import('./components/admin/dashboard')); const
> ServiceList = React.lazy(() =>
> import('./components/admin/serviceList')); const NewService =
> React.lazy(() => import('./components/admin/service_new')); const
> UpdateService = React.lazy(() =>
> import('./components/admin/updateService')); const SubcategorieNew =
> React.lazy(() => import('./components/admin/subcategorie_new')); const
> UpdateProduct = React.lazy(() =>
> import('./components/admin/updateProduct')); const UserList =
> React.lazy(() => import('./components/admin/UserList')); const
> UpdateUser = React.lazy(() =>
> import('./components/admin/updateUser')); const Employee =
> React.lazy(() => import('./components/admin/employee')); const
> ListReviews= React.lazy(()=> import('./components/admin/listReviews'))
> function App() {   useEffect(() => {
> store.dispatch(loadUser())   }, [])   return (
>
>
>
> <Suspense fallback={
>
> ### loading
>
> }>
>
> <Route path='/' element={}>
> <Route path='/home' element={}>
> <Route path='/banner' element={}>
> <Route path='/about' element={}>
> <Route path='/services' element={}>
> <Route path='/service/:id' element={}>
> <Route path='/login' element={}>
> <Route path='/register' element={}>
> <Route path='/MyProfile' element={}>
> <Route path='/MyProfile/update' element={}>
> <Route path='/MyProfile/updatePassword' element={}>
> <Route path='/forgotPassword' element={}>
> <Route path='/resetPassword/:token' element={}>
> <Route path='/reviews' element={}>
> <Route path='/comentarios' element={}>

Si alguien me pudiera ayudar

Answer (score 1):

Para los que tienen el mismo error que yo asi lo solucione yo, hay que revisar nuestra configuración de nodeJs,
Asi lo tenia yo

```html
const express= require("express");
const path = require("path");
const cookieParser=require("cookie-parser")
const fileUpload=require('express-fileupload')
const bodyParser=require('body-parser')
const errorMiddleware=require("./middleware/error")
const rutas=require('./routes/routers');

const app= express();


app.use(express.json({limit : 52428800,extended : true}))
app.use(express.urlencoded({limit : 52428800,extended : true}))
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true, limit: 52428800}))
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(fileUpload())


app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../fronted/build')));
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../fronted/build', 'index.html'));
});

//importo las rutas
app.use('/api', rutas)

//Middleware para manejar errores
app.use(errorMiddleware)

module.exports=app
```

y tenia que reorganizar mi codigo de esta manera y  cambiar el app.get('/', (req, res) => { el "/" por "*"

```html
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../fronted/build')));

app.use('/api', rutas);

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../fronted/build', 'index.html'));
});
```

con esos cambios me funciono ya no me tira mas el error Cannot GET /home al refrescar la pagina.
Espero que les funcione como a mi

Comment: Muy bien pero ¿Que significa "*" y porque se debe usar en vez de "/"?

Comment: @g.4 eso es lo que estaba pensando, no es un comodín para todas las rutas? Si es así no debería necesitar hacer eso

Comment: Me surgió esa duda @infinit3Loop__ por lo mismo que mencionaste, le di votos positivos a la respuesta de Michell porque si resolvió el problema pero espero que le de una doble revisión y agregue mas detalles, saludos

Comment: La solución es correcta ya que las rutas de express se setean de arriba hacia abajo entonces basicamente esta diciendo, si mi path inicial es /api los metodos son los que defino en rutas, para todo lo demás (*) que no esté listado anteriormente lo voy a responder enviando el archivo index.html